# Query to show all data unless related to user

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query which does exactly what I want.  Essentially, think of Twitter.  You don't want your homescreen to be full of every tweet ever by anyone from most recent on down.  You want only your friends.  That's what this does.

`profile_follows` is the table where connections are made.  `user_id` is you, `follow_id` is the `user_id` of the person you are following.

```
SELECT b.item, b.item_id, a.review_id, a.review, c.category, u.username, c.cat_id 
FROM reviews a
INNER JOIN items b
     ON a.item_id = b.item_id
INNER JOIN master_cat c
     ON c.cat_id = b.cat_id
INNER JOIN profile_follow pf
     ON pf.follow_id = a.user_id
INNER JOIN users u
     ON u.user_id = a.user_id
WHERE pf.user_id = '{$user_id}'
ORDER BY a.review_id DESC;
```

Here is the question:  How can I achieve the exact opposite?  Where it shows recent activity from everyone EXCEPT those you are following?

I tried various combos of 'ON pf.follow_id <> a.user_id', but that did not work.  Any other ideas?

TO summarize, it should select all `a.user_id`'s unless all  `a.user_id` = `follow_id`'s that matches with the {$user_id) (being passed in via `php`) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT b.item, b.item_id, a.review_id, a.review, c.category, u.username, c.cat_id 
FROM reviews a
INNER JOIN items b
     ON a.item_id = b.item_id
INNER JOIN master_cat c
     ON c.cat_id = b.cat_id
INNER JOIN users u
     ON u.user_id = a.user_id
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM profile_follow WHERE user_id = '{$user_id}' AND follow_id = a.user_id)
ORDER BY a.review_id DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
WHERE pf.user_id = '{$user_id}'
```

to

```
WHERE pf.user_id != '{$user_id}'
```

or

```
WHERE NOT pf.user_id = '{$user_id}'
```

or

```
WHERE pf.user_id NOT IN ('{$user_id}')
```